# UIViewController setValue:forUndefinedKey: with deleted xib

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib, nsunknownkeyexception

I recently **deleted the xib** for a particular UIViewController subclass. However, since then I have been getting the following error on device only, and not simulator:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<CustomWebViewController 0x192494d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key btnBack.'
```

I had set btnBack as an IBOutlet before in the XIB, and have since removed that property.

The XIB is deleted and I have cleaned the project countless times, but this issue still persists.

How can I go about finding where in my code this property is being set, or cleaning up this issue in XCode?

EDIT:
To make this clear:

- The xib used to exist, but has since been deleted.
- All IBOutlet properties have been deleted as well.
- The instantiation of the viewController happens using only code.
- If I had not deleted the properties then this would not have happened.
- This is probably an XCode bug, and I am hoping someone has faced this issue as well and solved it.

Comment: Yesterday I answered for this question for someone. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893344/nsunknownkeyexception-error-in-app-delegate/33894205#33894205 refer this link.

Comment: If it works,please up vote that links.

Comment: I know about this fix. But my situation is different. The point is that the XIB has been deleted altogether and is not being referenced anywhere in the code

Comment: Check whether you are instantiating the view controller from the nib even after deleting the nib.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the same... the xib does not exist at all, and no reference to it either

Comment: Have u deleted  just xib or its UIViewController class also.. ??

Comment: I have deleted the XIB only (the viewcontroller now is instantiated only using code), this is an XCode bug, and I am hoping someone has faced this issue beforehand,

Comment: Is this your FirstViewController(Home or RootViewController)?

Comment: Nope, it is being presented modally.

Comment: Show me the coding please.

Comment: Where does this happen? I mean does it happen when you navigating from one view to another view?

Comment: This happens when instantiating the CustomWebViewController using `[[CustomWebViewController alloc] init]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96115/discussion-between-user3182143-and-zemoon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what really happened, but I hadn't yet overridden the -init method int the class.

After overriding all the init methods like so:

```
-(instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {

    }

    return self;
}

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {

    }

    return self;
}

-(instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])
    {

    }

    return self;
}
```

Everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at connection inspector.
Is View  properly connected to File's owner and btnBack connection removed properly?

Comment: The XIB has been deleted, and now everything is being set in code. But I am still getting this issue.

Comment: Am confused! Is there an IBOutlet before your declaration?

Comment: The property used to exist when the xib was being used, now the xib as well as the property have been deleted

Comment: This is an XCode bug, but I am hoping someone has encountered the same